# Preventing double bookings in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm stuck on this problem where I want to prevent double bookings from happening. This is the code I've been using:

```
USE INL5
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_bookinginfo_doublebooking] ON [dbo].[bookinginfo] 
FOR INSERT AS 
DECLARE @startdate AS DATE 
DECLARE @enddate AS DATE 
DECLARE @roomnumber AS CHAR(3) 

SELECT @startdate = inserted.startdate, @enddate = inserted.enddate, @roomnumber = inserted.roomnumber 
FROM inserted, bookinginfo 
WHERE @roomnumber = bookinginfo.roomnumber AND (@startdate BETWEEN bookinginfo.startdate AND bookinginfo.enddate) AND (@enddate BETWEEN bookinginfo.startdate AND bookinginfo.enddate) 
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) 

BEGIN RAISERROR ('Double bookings are not allowed',16,1) 
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
END
```

The problem is that the error happens whether or not the dates are overlapping. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement:

```
SELECT @startdate = inserted.startdate, @enddate = inserted.enddate, 
       @roomnumber = inserted.roomnumber 
FROM inserted, bookinginfo 
WHERE @roomnumber = bookinginfo.roomnumber AND
     (@startdate BETWEEN bookinginfo.startdate AND bookinginfo.enddate) AND 
     (@enddate BETWEEN bookinginfo.startdate AND bookinginfo.enddate)
```

Is *highly* suspect.  You are assigning variables in the `select` and using the same variables in the `where`.  Is there an issue with expressing this as a normal `join`?

```
SELECT @startdate = i.startdate, @enddate = i.enddate, @roomnumber = i.roomnumber 
FROM inserted i JOIN
     bookinginfo bi
     ON i.roomnumber = bi.roomnumber AND
        (i.startdate BETWEEN bi.startdate AND bi.enddate) AND 
        (i.enddate BETWEEN bi.startdate AND bi.enddate) AND
        i.BookinginfoID <> bi.BookinginfoID;
```

This still doesn't do what you want for two reasons.  First, this logic is incorrect.  And two, the `if` isn't even using it.  I think the following is what you want for the body of the trigger:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM inserted i JOIN
                 bookinginfo bi
                 ON i.roomnumber = bi.roomnumber AND
                    i.startdate <= bi.enddate AND 
                    i.enddate >= bi.startdate AND
                    i.BookinginfoID <> bi.BookinginfoID;
           )
BEGIN
     RAISERROR ('Double bookings are not allowed',16,1)
     . . . 
END;
```

Comment: I tried the last part but it's still not working. Now the problem is that double bookings go through without the error ever happening. Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: I solved it by adding i.BookinginfoID <> bi.BookinginfoID to the ON-statement after  i.enddate >= bi.startdate. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3428812 . . . Yes, that is absolutely needed as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of that last `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)` . U are not checking just before selected value, just every inseterted value. It will always return u something.

It should look like that:

```
USE INL5
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_bookinginfo_doublebooking] ON [dbo].[bookinginfo] 
FOR INSERT AS 
DECLARE @startdate AS DATE 
DECLARE @enddate AS DATE 
DECLARE @roomnumber AS CHAR(3) 

IF EXISTS(SELECT @startdate = inserted.startdate, @enddate = inserted.enddate, @roomnumber = inserted.roomnumber 
FROM inserted, bookinginfo 
WHERE @roomnumber = bookinginfo.roomnumber AND (@startdate BETWEEN bookinginfo.startdate AND bookinginfo.enddate) AND (@enddate BETWEEN bookinginfo.startdate AND bookinginfo.enddate) ) 

BEGIN RAISERROR ('Double bookings are not allowed',16,1) 
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
END
```