# Trigger to prevent double bookings always flagging up

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having an issue where a trigger is always flagging up positive, even though from what I can tell it's conditions aren't being met. I want it to flag up when 3 criteria match identically to another booking, however whenever I run it with any data it seems to return a false positive.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.doubleBookRevised
ON dbo.tblBookingDetailsRevised
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF Exists (SELECT * FROM inserted i JOIN
dbo.tblBookingDetailsRevised bdr
ON i.locationID = bdr.locationID AND
i.bookedFor = bdr.bookedFor AND
i.bookedTimeSlot = bdr.bookedTimeSlot)
BEGIN RAISERROR ('Double bookings are not allowed.', 16, 1)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
RETURN
END
GO
```

I'd already implemented some logic in the C# front end to prevent double bookings, but when I ran the program it would succeed in the front end validation, but flag a false positive trying to write to the table.

I had used this for reference, but can't understand what is different about my implementation than the solution here.
[Preventing double bookings in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066359/preventing-double-bookings-in-sql)

*EDIT: Following advice I've ammended the trigger from an AFTER INSERT to INSTEAD OF INSERT to the following;*

```
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
IF (NOT Exists (SELECT * FROM inserted i JOIN
dbo.tblBookingDetailsRevised bdr
ON (i.locationID = bdr.locationID) AND
(i.bookedFor = bdr.bookedFor) AND
(i.bookedTimeSlot = bdr.bookedTimeSlot)))
INSERT INTO tblBookingDetailsRevised (bookingID, bookedFor, locationID, bookedTimeSlot, detailEquip) 
SELECT i.bookingID, i.bookedFor, i.locationID, i.bookedTimeSlot, i.detailEquip 
FROM inserted i
ELSE
BEGIN RAISERROR ('Double bookings are not allowed.', 16, 1)
RETURN
END
```

Comment: Have you tried using a UNIQUE constraint?

Comment: Your trigger is an `AFTER INSERT`, so you're checking a table for a booking that you have just inserted too. If you put a blue ball in a bag, and then check if there's a blue ball in bag, there will always be one in there. This seems like a job for unique index/constraint.

Comment: Be careful here. Rolling back the transaction in a trigger can be problematic. If you have another transaction outside of the insert statement you are going to have problems.

Comment: @LuisCazares the issue is that the unique identifiers being looked at are only unique when viewed together; otherwise I could rely on the primary keys to prevent it. To give a bit of context, the bookedFor value is a date, but it combined with a unique key make the primary key of another table which are inherited as part of the composite key here, and you can have multiple of the same date and different location or time etc.
I will try and implement the INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger instead

Answer (score 1):

The problem as posted can be solved with a simple UNIQUE CONSTRAINT that includes the 3 columns. There's no reason to reinvent the wheel.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblBookingDetailsRevised 
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_BookingDetailsRevised UNIQUE (locationID, bookedFor, bookedTimeSlot);
```

Unless there's something else happening and information is missing in the question.

Comment: This sounds like the correct solution . . . avoid a trigger entirely.

Comment: Ah, yeah that seems much easier and cleaner a solution

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `AFTER INSERT` trigger which means that the row is inserted before the `IF EXISTS` check in the trigger fires. Since it is within the same transaction of the insert then you will match on the recently added row and will get a positive result.  If you want to catch it before the insert then use an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger and handle the insert within the trigger.

Comment: I have tried implementing an ```INSTEAD OF INSERT``` statement as you suggested, however I've noticed when I do it shows "1 row affected" twice in the "results" tab of SQL Server Manager. I was curious if I've made a mistake in the implementation; I've edited the new Trigger into the original post

Comment: That is normal.  SQL server reports the initial insert and the trigger insert as separate commands even though the `INSTEAD OF INSERT` replaces the `INSERT`.